# How to trust an association id parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, strong-parameters

Here's an example of where we need to trust that the `conversation_id` wasn't altered by the user:

```rb
# messages_controller.rb
def create
  @message = Message.new(
    body: message_params[:body], # trustworthy
    user_id: current_user.id, # trustworthy
    conversation_id: message_params[:conversation_id] # not trustworthy!
    )
  @message.save
end
```

So I considered wrapping the above code in an `if` statement like so

```rb
# messages_controller.rb
def create
  if current_user.conversations.pluck(:id).include? message_params[:conversation_id]
    @message = Message.new(
      body: message_params[:body], 
      user_id: current_user.id, 
      conversation_id: message_params[:conversation_id] 
      )
    @message.save
  end
end
```

This is the only way I can think of to ensure that the conversation is actually one that the user belongs to (failing to check this carefully could result in a malicious user successfully writing messages to *other* people's conversations!)

Since this type of check must be fairly common, I just want to know have I done it effectively and efficiently, or is there a better way or more 'rails way'?

I should also add, I have cancan protecting the create method when the message doesn't belong to a conversation involving the user (which should completely prevent mischief on its own) AND I'm using uuid's on the conversation_id (which I know isn't really protection, but it all helps). But I still want to know how I can do this without those protections so as to add depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails way to do this would be to use a nested route instead of passing `conversation_id` through the request body:

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :messages, shallow: true
end
```

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # POST /conversations/:conversation_id/messages
  def create
    @conversation = current_user.conversations
                                .find(params[:conversation_id])
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params) do |m|
      m.user = current_user
    end

    if @message.save
      redirect_to @conversation
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def message_parameters
    params.require(:message)
          .permit(:body)
  end
end
```

This works - but its pretty far from perfect. If `@conversation = current_user.conversations.find(params[:conversation_id])` does not find a record we get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception and 404 response instead of a check if the user is authorized to post to that conversation.

A better solution would be to use something like:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
unless conversations.users.exist?(id: current_user.id)
  raise SomeKindOfAuthenticationError
end
```

Of course you should really be using something like Pundit instead of reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Just a question regarding using the nested routes, could a malicious user simply POST to a different route and trick the app that way? e.g. `/conversations/<conversation id belonging to someone else>/messages`

Comment: And if so, does that mean, the only true way to prevent this kind of mischief is to use pundit/cancan ?

Comment: Yes - any way you go around this that ID is coming from the user and you can't actually "trust" it. You always need to use authorization checks. Using a UUID won't actually make this more secure besides making it harder to do enumeration.